# dnsmasq dhcp. No errors... but not working. What's wrong?

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

Ubuntu 18.04
installed docker jpillora/dnsmasq

With default config, there's no DHCP so I grabbed the example config file from dnsmasq proper and these are the options I'm using:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
filterwin2k
no-resolv
dhcp-option=vendor:MSFT,2,1i
dhcp-range=192.168.30.10,192.168.30.99,12h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.30.1
server=/fake.duckdns.org/192.168.30.103
address=/myfaketestserver.net/192.168.30.102
address=/mytest.fake.duckdns.org/192.168.30.113
log-queries
log-dhcp
```

restarting, this is the entirety of the log:

```
⁣⁣dnsmasq: started, version 2.80 cachesize 150
⁣⁣dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
⁣⁣dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCP, IP range 192.168.30.10 -- 192.168.30.99, lease time 12h
⁣⁣dnsmasq: using nameserver 192.168.30.103#53 for domain fake.duckdns.org 
⁣⁣dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
```

On my windows machine, IPCONFIG /release IPCONFIG /renew and one of two things happend:

1) If I've restricted my ISP provided modem/router's DHCP to 192.168.30.99-255 then I pick up an IP in that range.
2) If I've restricted my router's DHCP to a prohibitively small range (so that just the server dnsmasq is running on can have it - and that IP is reserved) that there's no room for this machine, nothing happens.  It seems to hang.

In both cases, no entries are added to the log.

I haven't yet tried to define a static IP on the server and turn off the router's DHCP entirely, but I suspect that will result in the same as #2.  Besides, I really don't want to turn off my router's DHCP entirely.  I don't really want my network having to rely on this server.

The whole reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to have my media server accessible from inside and outside the network without having to put in a dozen entries into each device's hosts file.  So the Internet told me the "simple" thing to do was setup an internal DNS server.  That didn't work, so I think I learned that it also has to be a DHCP server and that's not working either.   This has ruined my entire weekend so I'm hoping I can get some help.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm..  OK, but I had read multiple guides that said it was fine as long as there were no IP conflicts.  Is that not true?

Comment: I guess it would be possible but to avoid confusion to use DHCP reservations would probably be the best choice in it.  In the data center environment that I work in, we do clustering of DHCP servers for fail over purposes as the information is synced between them all, but we only have one per VLAN / Physical area enabled at a time.  It seems to work.  I was also reading [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/368512/can-i-have-multiple-dhcp-servers-on-one-network) that it is possible, but when I was working in a game studio, someone plugged in a router and it took the network down.

Comment: If that was actually to work though, your router starts at the same IP address as the DHCP server ends of .99.  That would have to change to .100 to start the next one.